# Error en indices de array

Tags: java

Porque el indice `i` del primer `for` llega hasta `i>0` y porque el indice `i` de la clase main llega a `i>=0`  ?  porque si pongo en el primer `for i>=0` me da error al ejecutar.

```
public String[] invertirArray(String[] palabrasPaInvertir) {
        String[] cadenaInvertida = new String[palabrasPaInvertir.length-1];
        int j=0;
          for (int i = palabrasPaInvertir.length-1; i > 0; i--) {

            cadenaInvertida[j] =  palabrasPaInvertir[i];
             j++;
        }
        return cadenaInvertida;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArregloDeCadenas arreglo = new ArregloDeCadenas();

        String[] aux1={"mundo","viva","hola"};
        String[] cadena = arreglo.invertirArray(aux1);

          for (int i =aux1.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
           System.out.println(aux1[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta linea

```
String[] cadenaInvertida = new String[palabrasPaInvertir.length-1];
```

Le dices al arreglo `cadenaInvertida` que tendrá un largo de el lenght - 1. Si el arreglo `palabrasPaInvertir` tiene 9 (0 al 8 en indices) el arreglo `cadenaInvertida` tendrá 8 (del 0 al 7 en indices). Por lo tanto fallara al recorrer el ciclo for. Tienes que asignarle el largo igual al arreglo principal.

```
String[] cadenaInvertida = new String[palabrasPaInvertir.length];
```

Otra manera de revetir el arreglo es utilizar `List` y utilizar la funcion `Collections.reverse`

```
List<String> cadenaInvertida  = Arrays.asList(palabrasPaInvertir);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(cadenaInvertida);
```

Answer (score 2):

Porque creas un arreglo con 1 menos de longitud:

```
String[] cadenaInvertida = new String[palabrasPaInvertir.length-1];
```

Seria:

```
String[] cadenaInvertida = new String[palabrasPaInvertir.length];
```